# Texture maps/UV maps template

Tags: unity-game-engine

Within Unity, I understand that textures are mapped to 3d objects. For my example I have a cube, and I would like to map a Minecraft-style image to this that has a different top and sides.

How do I actually create the texture map though? The only way I have seen to do so is to create a cubemap in unity, however, the finished item only seems to work with a sky box and not my object cubes.

Is there a template to follow either within Unity or 3rd party that allows me to drop in the different textures to the boxes and then generate a final texture map?

Comment: This is called UV unwrapping, you can find how to unwrap and map it in the manual of any 3D modeling software.